# If an Activity takes long time to Load, it asks for force close, how to solve this?

Tags: android

Almost all the activities in my application need to interact with a web server to get data and then load the Activity screens. So at any moment if the internet is slow, it takes a lot of time and after some 12-15 secs it says "unable to load, ForceClose/Wait". How does applications avoid this? What is the solution they follow, when 1st 3-4 activities work fine (when net is good) then some Activity takes long(because of bad internet/ if internet is gone)

Comment: Check for internet connectivity before you get data from web server

Comment: you mean i should do this check before any server connection in any Activity, and show some Toast saying no internet connection?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You will find code for that through googling.....

Comment: me too facing the same problem.. slow internet leads to force close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Optimizing your code, Secondly do your Network/Internet work on a separate thread(like AsynTask).

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

This will not block your UI.

Hope This Help

Comment: Actually i am using a splash screen after the login screen. While showing Splash Screen, all these connections and fetching data is done, on a different thread. But the problem is, when internet is slow, login is successful but splash screen needs some 20-30 secs to do all these data fetching....so eventually application asks for Force Close...thats my main issue

Answer (score 1):

Its a problem of slow internet connections. I have also faced it earlier while making an app which used to fetch data from a web server. So there are 4 things which can help you in this matter:
(1) Check if there is any internet connection or not:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)   getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni!=null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
```

If there is no internet connection then you can inform the user about it by a Dialog.

(2) If there is an internet connection but its very slow, then you can put some code for waiting for the response for a certain time and then showing a Dialog to user for waiting or aborting the request.

(3) One more thing which is very useful - use slide_in_left and slide_out_right anim styles in place of fade_in and fade_out for transitions between intents. It helps a lot, the screen goes black very rarely.

```
     try    {           
        Intent yourIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), YourActivity.class);      
        startActivityForResult(yourIntent, 0);      
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);        
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
```

(4) Use AsyncTask for sending the requests to web.

Comment: can you please elaborate on 3rd point??...what exactly it is...and where to use and how is it useful

Comment: It is basically a way to go to another activity from this activity. Here YourActivity.class is the activity to which you are trying to go from the present activity.

Comment: no, not that....what i want to know is the use of 3rd step in that try block??...i dont know anything about transition anims

Comment: the method overridePendingTransition() defines a way of transition. There are a lot of styles in which you can go to another activity. You should google about it.

Comment: okay....instead of the default transition like - new activity comes sliding from right to left?....thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if there is an existing internet or data connection prior to making the call. You should also be able to specify a certain length of time to try and load the file, then display an error or try again as desired.