# Slow Internet connection leads to force close

Tags: android

I am developing an android application where in each activity i need to pass some data onto the server and get back the responses before going to the next activity. The application works fine if the internet is fast enough. But as the speed goes down the application force closes. How to deal with slow internet connection so that it might not lead to force close of application?????

Here is some part of code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    if(userFunction.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
    {
        answer="";
        for(int check1=0;check1<counter2;check1++){
            int check2=0;
            answer=answer+option4[check1]+"|";
            while(check2<counter1){
                if(edTxt[check1][check2].getText().toString().equals("")){
                    answer="";
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    answer=answer+edTxt[check1][check2].getText().toString()+"|";
                }
                check2++;       
            }   
            if(answer.equals("")){
                break;
            }
            else{
                answer=answer+"||";
            }
        }
        if(answer.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all fields", 600).show();
        }
        else{
        userFunction.form1(surveyId,userId , quesNo, answer);
        if(total>0){
            draw(temp); 
        }
        else{
            ques_no++;
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quesNo", Integer.toString(ques_no)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("surveyId", surveyId));
            count = getJsonFromURL22(surveyCond, params);           
            j=Integer.parseInt(result);
            if(j==22)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Survey Completed", 600).show();
                Intent home=new Intent(Format16.this, SurveyCompleted.class);
                UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
                userFunctions.full(surveyId);
                Bundle d=new Bundle();
                d.putString("userId", userId);
                home.putExtras(d);
                startActivity(home);
            }
     public String getJsonFromURL22(String url, List<NameValuePair> params){
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
}
//convert response to string
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(reader.readLine());

    String line="0";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. And the logcat error too.

Comment: you are doing networking proceed in different thread right ?

Comment: You should check out this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150583/if-an-activity-takes-long-time-to-load-it-asks-for-force-close-how-to-solve-th/11150845#11150845

Comment: You should check out this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150583/if-an-activity-takes-long-time-to-load-it-asks-for-force-close-how-to-solve-th/11150845#11150845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application works fine if the internet is fast enough. But as the
>   speed goes down the application force closes.

It clearly indicates that you are doing network operation on UI Thread.As per Google Docs if the Asynchronous operation is performed on Main thread and if it is taking more than 5 seconds then your application will show force close dialog which is very unpleasent for end user.

In-fact if you try to run such application on latest android version (i.e 4.0 or later) It will not allow you to run application it will crash at start as soon as it detects that the asynchronous operation is performed on main thread.

You must use `AsyncTask` or `Handlers` to perform long running application.

Go through following blog to know more.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: Yeah there are tons of example out there if you face any difficulty :)

Comment: Another good link is : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not shown any code, I am guessing you are targeting Android API level 10 or lower, and you are doing all the networking in the UI thread, resulting in the dreaded App Not Responding(ANR) error. One way to fix the problem would be to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and move all your networking code in there. When done right, `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` will process all your networking in a separate thread, allowing the UI to remain responsive.

It usually works something like this:

```
private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           // Do all networking here, this will work away in a background thread.
           // In your case:
           // HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           // Must happen here
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
         // dismiss progress dialog if any (not required, runs in UI thread)
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         // show progress dialog if any, and other initialization (not required, runs in UI thread)
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
// update progress, and other initialization (not required, runs in UI thread)
      }
}
```

If you enable [`StrictMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html), or target api versions 11 and higher, Android will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when you try to do this.

Comment: i have used this method... seems like itz working for me... :) :)

Answer (score 0):

That must be ANR issue not the Force Close issue.

You can use StrictMode to help find potentially long running operations such as network that you might accidentally be doing your main thread.

Or else try to put  progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this tool that allows you to see what is causing the slow down in your application. The ARO tool is designed to diagnose these sorts of network problems http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700312